# errorType 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' in Assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlclient

On local work ok but when I publish to production it give me in log file this error
In log file:

```
03/07/2014 17:15-->
Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' 
in Assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' 
is not marked as serializable.; 
Stack Trace:    
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(       RuntimeType type)     
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.WriteValueToStream(Object value, BinaryWriter writer); Source: mscorlib
------------------
```

what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you storing something with a database connection in session state?

Comment: You need to add more details about where are you getting this error like a webservice etc. and what you are trying to do when you get this error.

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi in .aspx.cs I have a  [WebMethod]public static void AddComment than insert in db one row, I call this method from js PageMethods.AddComment= function(productID,stars,hiddAdv,hiddWeak,header,hiddComment,dateTime,onSuccess,onFailed,userContext)  if is the error onFailed return alert(error): there was am error processing the request and in Log As I wrote above